# Can you get Class Specific Armor for other classes?

Tags: destiny

I have noticed that some things are across-profile (Glimmer for example)and you can store things in the vaults that can be used by other characters, so I was wondering, is it possible to find (for example) Hunter-Class armour as a Warlock?

Comment: Yea you can I am a Warlock and I got legendary titan legs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

It's happened to me a few times.

Comment: Can you give any more information here?

Comment: I'm not sure what more you need... as any class it is possible that your engrams will become class specific armor for other classes. Is there more to the question that I'm missing?

Comment: Have also had it happen.  Worst (best?) I've had was a legendary engram became legendary boots for another class.

Comment: Can also say it is possible, although it seems somewhat rare.

Comment: First time it happened to me was my first purple armor piece... for a different class :(

Comment: Purple/Exotic Gear Engrams usually say (Random Class) under what they can decode into, so not very surprising.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur on occasion with Legendary and Exotic Engrams, also Xur (feel free to edit in the thing on the u) a special vendor who only appears on weekends sells assorted equipment for all classes.